# String split with Dot character not working

Tags: java, string

I have a simple string with the value "45.7961887"

I want split this variable using the "." as separator.

But when split, the string array result is empty.

Image with the value:
[Image with the string value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3mXK.png)

Now, with the split:
[Image with the split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgFre.png)

Comment: Don't post code as images

Comment: You need to escape the . character because split takes a regEx as input and dot is meta character for Regular Expression /.. Read the link above . Also Android Studio has nothing to do with it neither Android .. its only Java basics ,,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you escape the dot? `string.split("\\.")` or `string.split("[.]")`